# Next-Auth Email verificationToken

Tags: prisma, next-auth

I have next-auth setup with the EmailProvider working beautifully sending magic links for new and existing user sign in's but I want to use it also as a "shared link" that is sent to new or existing users.
I am hoping to recreate the magic link with a callback to send the invitee to a particular part of the website. If the invitee has already joined then fine or add them as a new user.
I have successfully created a URL link that is exactly that which is supplied by Next-auth for a magic Link and I am creating a VerificationToken successfully in my VerificationToken table in Prisma database with identifier, expiry and token (randow crypto key copied straight from next-auth's function).
For example

```
 http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/email?callbackUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fdiscover%2Fclmv53oh80015hkdsy7e2fjoj&token=bcb6e15aa45122c2333bde128523fe2da0e46c16b7b66ad4abce88b145862e1d&email=palmer.sdp%40gmail.com
```

However when I navigate to this URL I expect it to go to a Sign in page -> sign in -> then redirected to this CallbackUrl.

**What am I missing? Is there something else Next-Auth checks other than the verification token and expiry?**